# DEBIAN - Issue with installing systemd-coredump as part of package installation

Tags: debian, systemd-coredump

I'm using debian (buster) for building my packages.

I'm trying to add `systemd-coredump` to my package dependencies so it will be installed everytime I will install my package.

So, I've updated the control file so the package will be depended on `systemd-coredump` package.

```
Source: rmd-baseconfig
Section: admin
Priority: optional
Maintainer: NAME <MAIL>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 11),
Standards-Version: 4.5.1
Homepage: http://www.google.com

Package: rmd-baseconfig
Architecture: all
Depends: ${misc:Depends},
 systemd-coredump
Description: Base configuration for RMD device
```

And also add to debian rules, rule so it will enable `systemd-coredump`.

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# See debhelper(7) (uncomment to enable)
# output every command that modifies files on the build system.
#export DH_VERBOSE = 1

%:
    dh $@
    
override_dh_systemd_enable:
    dh_systemd_enable --name=coredump
```

The package is of course compiled successfully but when I'm trying to install it I
get the following error.

```
Preparing to unpack ../rmd-baseconfig_1.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking rmd-baseconfig (1.0) over (1.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rmd-baseconfig:
 rmd-baseconfig depends on systemd-coredump; however:
  Package systemd-coredump is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package rmd-baseconfig (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rmd-baseconfig
```

And after further investigation I think that this is the ERROR that prevent `systemd-coredump` to be installed (I recieved it when tried manually to install systemd-coredump by doing `apt install systemd-coredump`)

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 systemd-coredump : Depends: libdw1 (>= 0.158) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: systemd (= 241-7~deb10u8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Is there anyway to fix this issue? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that `dpkg -i` doesn't install dependencies.
When using `apt install <package_name>` everything was installed as needed.